# What are IDisposable alternative uses?

Tags: c#, idisposable, msdn

The msdn documentation of the System.IDisposable interface states that

> The **primary** use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.

I'm wondering what are alternative uses.

For example we also needed the IDisposable interface for other allocated resources, such as event subscription and so.

We used the interface as a marker to allow a class instance to know when it's no more used from clients. Client and infrastructural code explicitly call IDisposable.Dispose() whenever they no more need a logical instance of a class implementing the code.
There's no relation with unmanaged resources wrapped from the interface.

When we choosed the IDisposable interface for such a behaviour we considered it as an alternative (undocumented) use of the interface.

Which are the alternative use of IDisposable you have found?
Are they legittimate? Is the MSDN documentation wrong?

Comment: It seems you already answered your question.

Comment: If a class has no unmanaged resources, or IDisposable internals, does it need to know it is no longer used?

Comment: I'm even looking for objections to the use I did.

Comment: @Jodrell It could be needed from calling code too, for example if Dispose() throws InvalidOperationException becouse of some business logic related to the class use.
For example the instance could not be disposed right now, but the disposition is unrelated to unmanaged resources.
Would this be a legitimate use?

Comment: I'm not sure that is a legitimate use. IDisposable is used to message the implementing class that it is no longer required and this should not fail because of some expected asynchronous activity. For "upward" communication of state some other interface should be used. Exceptions should be used in exceptional cirmunstances. Maybe I just can't think if a good example?

Comment: It can be used to release managed resources as well (i.e. Database connections, Streams, etc.).  Another popular use (even used by some Microsoft APIs) is that it can be used to create scopes for certain actions -- (to be used with using blocks) -- for things like elevating permissions or setting a logging context, etc. -- It can also be used to cancel background tasks... -- All kinds of things.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio The Microsoft guidance for implementing IDisposable is that Dispose should *never* throw any kind of exception, (also, it should always allow itself to be called multiple times, and ignore the extra calls).

Comment: Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive") uses `IDisposable` to unsubscribe from subscriptions to observables. It's very convenient to use the `Dispose()` call to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your reading of the documentation is wrong. Saying that any usage of `IDisposable` that is not related to unmanaged resources is undocumented is a bit like saying that any usage of `System.Int32` that is not counting things is undocumented. It is an interface and has no implementation, there is no functionality there to even begin distinguishing between what's documented and what's undocumented.

The purpose of `IDisposable` is simply to provide the developer with a mechanism to deterministically control the lifetime of their objects. It just so happens that this mainly a requirement for dealing with unmanaged resources.

One of the more fancy uses of `IDisposable` is the `using` block syntactic sugar. As others have mentioned, `using` blocks give an operation scope and I think those are quite elegant.

#### Example 1 - timing blocks

StackOverflow uses [mini profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) that uses `using` blocks to identify nested regions of execution:

```
using (profiler.Step("Doing complex stuff"))
{
    using (profiler.Step("Step A"))
    { // something more interesting here
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    using (profiler.Step("Step B"))
    { // and here
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
}
```

The alternative to not using `using` is pretty horrible and I don't even want to mock it up here.

#### Example 2 - Disposable action

There have been different variations of disposable action pattern making rounds in .NET Domain Driven Design circles. Ayende has [one](http://ayende.com/blog/890/the-ultimate-disposable), so does Udi Dahan in his [Domain Events implementation](http://www.udidahan.com/2008/08/25/domain-events-take-2/), Jimmmy Bogard has a [slightly different take on this](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/08/04/container-friendly-domain-events/), still in the context of Domain Events. The crux of the pattern is that you want to perform certain actions in some context, then have the context revert back to what it was before after you are done.

Ayende provides a simple example:

```
class UsuallyReadOnly { 
  //.. implementation
  public IDisposable AllowModification
  {
    get 
    {
        _allowModification = true;
        return new DisposableAction(()=>{ _allowModification = false; } );
     }
  }
}
```

And `UsuallyReadOnly`'s usage:

```
UsuallyReadOnly foo = new UsuallyReadOnly();
using(foo.AllowModification)
{
  foo.Name = "Bar";
}
```

Comment: I think that msdn miss an example unrelated to unmanaged resource/memory allocations. Yet your answer is the best I've found.

Answer (score 2):

`IDisposable` is often used in conjunction with using to activate and deactivate something in a definite scope even if it is not an unmanaged resource. The use you describes sound as a reference counting and for sure is not recommended.

Comment: I agree that's reference counting, per se, is to avoid at all.
Nevertheless, a class could need to know if it is no more used from the client, if it's "disposed".
Consider for example a class serialized: each time you deserialize it you get a new instance, but in the computational context it's always the same. IDisposable.Dispose() would tell the instance that it's to be disposed from the computational context.

Answer (score 1):

For "resources", substitute "responsibilities".  When an object is said to hold an unmanaged resource, what that really means is that there is some task that needs to get done sometime, and the object is the only thing with the information and impetus necessary to do it.  The purpose of "Dispose" isn't to get rid of any tangible entity, but rather to allow an object to "put its affairs in order".  Someone is putting his affairs in order before his death isn't doing anything to himself, but rather he is ensuring that the things he has to do to persons and things outside himself get done.  Likewise with IDisposable.Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

Remember there is also the **using** pattern which acts a bit like **RAII**.

```
using ( DisposableObject obj = new DisposableObject( ) )
{

    .....
}
```

So `Dispose` gets called when the using block is exited.

Answer (score 0):

One of the more popular uses of the `IDisposable` interface is transaction scopes. You can use it to wrap some SQL logic in a transaction, and explicitly call `Complete()` to end the transaction:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
    {
        // perform sql logic
        ...

        scope.Complete(); 
    }
}
```

You could also use a similar pattern for just about anything that requires a temporary function, such as creating and deleting a temporary file:

```
public class TempFileProvider : IDisposable
{
    public Filename { get; private set; }

    public TempFileProvider()
    {
        Filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {   
        File.Delete(Filename);
    }
}
```

So you could use it like:

```
using (var tempFileProvider = new TempFileProvider())
{
    DoSomethingWithFile(tempFileProvider.Filename);
} // deletes temp file
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following question [Need an alternative to my IDisposable Hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397789/need-an-alternative-to-my-idisposable-hack)

There i give a nice example of what i used IDisposable for. :)

Granted, it is not the ideal solution, however, it helped me a lot.