# Need an alternative to my IDisposable Hack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i currently have a scenario where i re-use blocks of html code. i basically have a div container, and i re-use that container and variants thereof throughout the site.

the container consists of the following html:

```
<div class="c_wrapper">
    <div class="c_content">
        CONTENT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

**please note that there are alot more to the container than i specify, this is a basic framework.*

instead of re-typing the container code on multiple times i on each page, i made use of IDisposable to make it a little bit easier:

```
public static class Container
{
    public static ContainerHelper BeginContainer(this HtmlHelper content, int containerSize)
    {
        return new ContainerHelper(content, containerSize);
    }
}

public class ContainerHelper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper _content;
    public ContainerHelper(HtmlHelper content, int containerSize)
    {
        _content = content;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<div class=\"container_" + containerSize + "\">");
        _content.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("</div>");
        _content.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

This mean that i can now simply use the following whenever i want to use the container:

```
@using (Html.BeginContainer(24))
{
   <span>hello world... and other content here</span>
}
```

I want to take this a little further though, and i realize that IDisposable is not the ideal solution.

I want to be able to do the following:

```
@Html.Container(24)
{
   <span>hello world... and other content here</span>
}
```

Any suggestions on how i could achieve this? if it is not achievable, suggestions on how i can accomplish my first example without making use of IDisposable.

I am using MVC 3/4 and C#.

Thanx

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand.. but why can't you just call a function that returns an `IHtmlString`? Your example is not possible.. but perhaps my suggestion suits? By the way.. that isn't a hack. I use that in certain places all the time. In fact, I've seen many examples of extending HtmlHelpers the exact same way..

Comment: i write out html, so what ever i place in the brackets of my using gets wrapped with the div. can you give an example of how i will accomplish the same with IHtmlString?

Comment: My point is that you can't brace it in quite the same way as you do with `using`. There is no context in which that closing brace says "Okay, i'm done, dispose of me and call this code" quite like a `using` block. `using` works that way because its transformed into a `try..finally` "behind-the-scenes".

Comment: Not applicable to the discussion here, but the superfluous use of `StringBuilder` here is really bothering me. Maybe it shouldn't, but I can't help but be irked by it.

Comment: like i said, a lot more is happening and i add a few more lines of html with that stringbuilder, i just removed the bits that clogs up this question :)....

Comment: @DustyRoberts Ahh, my misunderstanding then. Carry on!

Comment: ASP.NET MVC uses `IDisposable` in their own helpers (for instance for the `<form>` construction). Anyone using MVC should be aware of this. imho ***using*** it is the preferred scenario here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your helper method take in a delegate. Phil Haack blgoged about this in [detail](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx)

```
public static HelperResult Container(int containerSize, Func<dynamic, HelperResult> template)
{
    return new HelperResult(writer => template(null).WriteTo(writer));
}


@Html.Container(24, @<span>hello world... and other content here</span>)
```

That would just output what you pass in. To wrap it with your `div` tags, make calls to the `writer` parameter in the `HelperResult`

The reason for the `Func<dynamic, HelperResult>` is that markup passed into the method is always passed in as a delegate that takes a single parameter and returns a `HelperResult`. In this case since you aren't passing in any data, I used `dynamic` to keep it simple, but if you read the link from above, you will see that you can pass in an object of any type and it can be accessed via a special variable called `item`.

Comment: This would be my suggestion too. A very cool piece of MVC that most people don't know about.

Comment: this helps alot, i marked it as the correct answer, just note that nesting these templates is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

That was quite clever. However, this kind of coding may end up causing some trouble for you later on. Suppose a colleague tries to use your class without knowing how it works (how it closes the div). Also suppose that someday you'll end up forgetting about what you did there, and you try using it outside a `using` block.

My suggestion: don't do any logic inside the `Dispose` method that doesn't have anything to do with real disposal. It's a matter of a method doing only what it's supposed to do. Instead, have a static method that takes whatever you want inside your div's. This method is the one that must wrap your html. Just like this:

```
public static string myMethod(string input)
{
    string result = "<div>" +
      // ...snip
      + input +
      // ...snip
      + "</div>";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I can't upvote this. `HtmlHelpers` are extended like this all the time. I see it everywhere. Even the framework makes gigantic use of this.

Comment: this means i need to pass my content as a string and it basically eliminates all possibilities of logic withing the using block. this solution wont help. I do however agree on the matter in which i use IDisposable here is not correct, hence me looking for an alternative

Comment: @DustyRoberts Why do you consider this (using `IDisposable` like this) bad practice when the entire ASP.NET MVC Framework makes use of it everywhere?

Comment: i am writing html in "C#"... plus... IDisposable is meant to assist in the cleaning of objects. i would have like a scenario where i could have some sort of "EditorTemplate" or "DisplayTemplate" where my html sits in my view pages. (dreaming :) or maybe even something like 'section()'

Comment: @DustyRoberts you can use logic there. You could, for example, have variables in the class to keep a state, some sort of a string buffer, and methods to change said state... And when you are all done, you simply output the whole thing in a Write method (in this case, I suggest making the method non static).

Comment: @Renan, i would rather make use of IDisposable than having a whole bunch of variables that i need to keep track of. in your example there is no way i can make use of javascript withing the string i pass through to your method, and if i want to make use of basic razor functions like Html.TextboxFor() i would have to keep on breaking out of the string being passed through to the method, or... do it outside the method... this example will definitely not work.